# Allow html in input default value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Just a quick question..

I am trying to generate an text input where the default value is nested in  tag with an inline css..just to make it look smaller and grayer than the normal input.

```
echo $this->Form->input( 'address', array('div'=>false, 'label'=>'', 'default'=>'<span style="font-size: 0.6em;color:#e3e3e3;">put your address here</span>', 'size'=>'50' ) );
```

after the user would click, the default value would be erased leaving it blank.

However cakephp generates the input with the value containing the html tags, i.e. .
How do I make cakephp unfilter the html in the default value?

I forgot what option to use in this situation and I tried everything that I can think of. I remember that I can do this by just adding some sort of value in the option array like `'html'=>false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to get an input box to render html inside itself. There is also nothing in the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput) to suggest what you want. It *is* possible to embed it within a div, and to include things before, after, and between the label and input. I think you need to use javascript to accomplish what you want to do.

```
<style>
.default {font-size: 0.6em;color:#e3e3e3;}
.normal {color:black;}
</style>
<script language='javascript'>
function change(input)
{
    input.classList.add("normal");
    if (input.value == "enter text here")
        input.value = "";
}
</script>
<form>
<input id='test' class='default' type='text' value='enter text here' onfocus='change(this);'>
</form>
```

Comment: is there really no way? I thought before that this can be done. I inherited a cake project before and I think it had a form where I can use <b></b> <em></em> tags in one of its inputs. Maybe my memory is failing me. I like your answer of using JS though I just thought that maybe this can be done in cake.

Comment: While you can change the style of an input box, you cannot get it to render html within it. If you worked on a previous project that used this I would expect them to have been extending the FormHelper with custom code.

Answer (score 1):

Put your helper text in your labels. If you put the default value as a HTML string the Input will display the HTML as it does not render HTML inside of it.

If you add the additional HTML to your label, you could use this http://trevordavis.net/blog/jquery-inline-form-labels to overlay the labels over the inputs.

```
echo $this->Form->input( 'address', array('div'=>false, 'label'=>'put your address here','size'=>'50' ) );
```

Also, this method allows you to apply the css externally instead of inline -- which is always best.

Comment: sorry, what i meant is having the HTML inside the input as a value. not as the label for the input.